# Compile QtWebEngine natively on Raspberry Pi

Tags: qt, qt5, raspberry-pi3, pkg-config, qtwebengine

I am trying to compile QtWebEngine on Raspberry Pi 3. Whole Qt library compiled ok, but when I'm trying to run make in the directory with QtWebEngine I get this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/qt5/qtwebengine$ /usr/local/qt5/bin/qmake 

Running configuration tests...
Done running configuration tests.

Configure summary:

Qt WebEngine:
  Embedded build ......................... yes
  Pepper Plugins ......................... no
  Printing and PDF ....................... no
  Proprietary Codecs ..................... no
  Spellchecker ........................... yes
  Native Spellchecker .................... no
  WebRTC ................................. no
  Use System Ninja ....................... no
  Geolocation ............................ no
  WebChannel support ..................... yes
  Use v8 snapshot ........................ yes
  Kerberos Authentication ................ no
  Building v8 snapshot supported ......... yes
  Use ALSA ............................... yes
  Use PulseAudio ......................... no
      Optional system libraries used:
    re2 .................................. no
    icu .................................. no
    libwebp, libwebpmux and libwebpdemux . no
    opus ................................. no
    ffmpeg ............................... no
    libvpx ............................... no
    snappy ............................... no
    glib ................................. no
    zlib ................................. no
    minizip .............................. no
    libevent ............................. no
    jsoncpp .............................. no
    protobuf ............................. no
    libxml2 and libxslt .................. no
    lcms2 ................................ no
    png .................................. no
    JPEG ................................. yes
    harfbuzz ............................. no
    freetype ............................. no
    x11 .................................. no
  Required system libraries:
    fontconfig ........................... no
    dbus ................................. no
    nss .................................. no
    khr .................................. yes
    glibc ................................ yes
  Required system libraries for qpa-xcb:
    libdrm ............................... no
    xcomposite ........................... no
    xcursor .............................. no
    xi ................................... no
    xtst ................................. no

WARNING: Thumb instruction set is required to build ffmpeg for QtWebEngine.

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'make install'.
Qt will be installed into '/usr/local/qt5'.

Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
the previous build.


pkg-config is required
QtWebEngine will not be built.
```

Questions:

1. Why it cannot be compiled? Because of `fontconfig`, `dbus` and `nss` libraries?
2. I've tried to install `libfontconfig1-dev` but it is already installed. The same with `dbus` and `nss`.
3. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing pkg-config and libs are not detected. Note "pkg-config is required". Most likely you compiled qt without pkg-config support.